# How to delete an object if its out of screen and it was used in raycasters of other objects?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, raycasting, phaserjs

On my main game class I have a `createCar` method, which dynamically creates a car and iterates over other cars and maps raycast between each other (so cars can detect distance between each other):

```
  createCar(scene, x, y, angle, speed, name) {
    const car = new Car(scene, x, y, angle, speed);
    car.name = name; // for debug
    this.carsGroup.children.iterate((c) => {
      c.raycaster.mapGameObjects(car, true);
      car.raycaster.mapGameObjects(c, true);
    });
    this.carsGroup.add(car);
  }
```

It works, unless I want to delete a car:

```
  update() {
    this.carsGroup.children.iterate((car) => {
      // Car is out of screen
      if (!this.cameras.main.worldView.contains(car.x, car.y)) {
        this.carsGroup.remove(car);
        this.carsGroup.children.iterate((c) => {
          c.raycaster.removeMappedObjects(car);
          car.raycaster.removeMappedObjects(c);
        });
        car.destroy();
      } else {
        car.update();
        car.debug();
      }
    });
  }
```

Then it fails here when internally it tries to retrieve the "raycasterMap" and destroy it:

```
object.data.get('raycasterMap').destroy();
```

raycaster-core.js:396 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy')
at Raycaster.removeMappedObjects (raycaster-core.js:396:48)
at game.js:51:23

I can't figure out how to properly remove a car from scene and memory.
If I just call `car.destroy()` other cars throw exceptions, because the raycast still has references.

Full codepen sample:
https://codepen.io/vvyshko/pen/bGOxpbG

Comment: Is my solution, what yourwhere looking for? or did or miss something?

Comment: Hey @winner_joiner, thank you for the help, but unfortunately, your solution also throws same exception: ```cast.js:72 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')   at Ray.cast (cast.js:72:31)  at Car.update (car.js:47:33)``` 

The exception thrown by the other car, not the one is deleted.

Comment: I think I will post an issue to https://github.com/wiserim/phaser-raycaster

Comment: The code should not throw any error, but it somehow stop. if you remove the **ray / raycast** `destroy` function calls, it works. Maybe your are not allowed to destroy them. Creating an Issue might surly help.

Comment: **btw.:** I updated my answer with the `destroy` functions calls, commented out, because I was testing it.

Comment: I guess the issue is that if we just destroy the object, it won't automatically disappear from the mapped lists of other objects. So next frame, other raycasters perform iteration on mapped objects the code fails.

Comment: Created an issue https://github.com/wiserim/phaser-raycaster/issues/48, hope @wiserim
will respond

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is, that the clean up is not optimal. I would suggest, put the cleanup into the `destroy` function of the `car` - class, and just add validation in the `update` function of the scene, checking if the `car`- child is a valid object,

**Here the alterations:**

```
class Car extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
  // ...
  destroy(){
    super.destroy();
    // Cleanup data
    this.ray.destroy();
    this.raycaster.destroy();
  }
  // ...
}

class Example extends Phaser.Scene {
  //...
  update() {
    this.carsGroup.children.iterate((car) => {
      // Check if the list item is valid
      if (!car) {
        return;
      }

      if (!this.cameras.main.worldView.contains(car.x, car.y)) {
        // Remove Car from Group and destroy Object
        this.carsGroup.remove(car, true, true);
      } else {
        car.update();
        car.debug();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Code copied and adapted from Codepen:**

```js
class Car extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
    constructor(scene, x, y, rotation, speed) {
      super(scene, x, y, "car");
      this.debugGraphics = scene.add.graphics();
      this.speed = speed;
      this.initialSpeed = speed;
      this.rayLength = 100;
      this.rayColor = 0xffffff;
      this.rotation = rotation;
      this.setDisplaySize(130, 80);
  
      this.debugColor = new Phaser.Display.Color();
      // Set the color to a random value
      this.debugColor.random();

      // Create a raycaster for the car
      this.raycaster = scene.raycasterPlugin.createRaycaster();
      // Create a ray for the car
      this.ray = this.raycaster.createRay();
      // Set the ray origin to the car position
      this.ray.setOrigin(this.x, this.y);
      // Set the ray angle to the car angle
      this.ray.setAngle(this.rotation);
  
      scene.physics.world.enable(this); // Enable physics for the car
      scene.add.existing(this); // Add the car to the scene
  
      //this.raycaster.mapGameObjects(scene.rectangle);
    }
  
    update() {
      // console.log('update', this.name, this.speed);
      window.lastUpdatedCar = this;
      this.raycaster.update();
      // Move the car forward
      this.scene.physics.velocityFromRotation(
        this.rotation,
        this.speed,
        this.body.velocity
      );
      // Update the ray origin and angle
      this.ray.setOrigin(this.x, this.y);
      this.ray.setAngle(this.rotation);
      // Cast the ray and get the intersection
     // console.log(this.name, 'removed=', this.removed)

      let intersection ;
      try {
        intersection = this.ray.cast()
      } catch (e) {}
      this.intersection = intersection;
      // If there is an intersection, reduce the speed or stop
      if (intersection) {
      //  console.log('!!!', intersection)
      }
      if (this.crashed) {
          this.setTint(0x555888);
        this.speed = 0;
      } else if (intersection && intersection.object) {
       // console.log('!!!', intersection)
        let distance = Phaser.Math.Distance.BetweenPoints(this, intersection);
        if (distance < this.rayLength) {
          // Determine a deceleration rate (you can adjust this value)
          const decelerationRate = 1; // Adjust as needed
  
          // Calculate the new speed with deceleration
          this.speed -= decelerationRate;
  
          // Ensure the speed doesn't become negative
          if (this.speed < 0) {
            this.speed = 0;
          }
        } else {
          if (this.speed < this.initialSpeed) {
            this.speed++;
          }
        }
      }
    }

  
  
  
    handleCollision(o1, o2) {
      console.log('CRASH', o1, o2)
      o1.crashed = true;
      o2.crashed = true;
    }
  
    debug() {
      this.debugGraphics.clear();
      this.debugGraphics.setDepth(this.depth + 1); // Set the depth
      
      this.debugGraphics.lineStyle(1, this.debugColor.color);
      this.debugGraphics.beginPath();
      this.debugGraphics.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
      this.debugGraphics.lineTo(
        this.x + Math.cos(this.rotation) * this.rayLength,
        this.y + Math.sin(this.rotation) * this.rayLength
      );
      this.debugGraphics.closePath();
      this.debugGraphics.strokePath();
  
      if (this.intersection) {
        this.debugGraphics.fillStyle(0xff0000, 0.5);
        this.debugGraphics.strokeCircle(
          this.intersection.x,
          this.intersection.y,
          5
        );
      }
  
      if (this.crashed) {
          // Draw a red cross
          this.debugGraphics.lineStyle(2, 0xff0000);
          this.debugGraphics.beginPath();
          this.debugGraphics.moveTo(this.x - 10, this.y - 10);
          this.debugGraphics.lineTo(this.x + 10, this.y + 10);
          this.debugGraphics.moveTo(this.x + 10, this.y - 10);
          this.debugGraphics.lineTo(this.x - 10, this.y + 10);
          this.debugGraphics.closePath();
          this.debugGraphics.strokePath();
      }
    }
  
    destroy(){
      super.destroy();
      // Cleanup data
      //this.ray.destroy();
      //this.raycaster.destroy();
    }
  }


class Example extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.setBaseURL("https://labs.phaser.io");
    this.load.image("bg", "assets/skies/space2.png");
    this.load.image("car", "assets/sprites/car-yellow.png");
    window.scene = this;
  }

  create() {
    const bg = this.add.image(0, 0, "bg");
    bg.setOrigin(0, 0); // Set the origin to the top-left corner
    bg.displayWidth = this.sys.game.config.width; // Stretch width to match canvas width
    bg.displayHeight = this.sys.game.config.height;

    // //create game object
    // this.rectangle = this.add
    //   .rectangle(1000, 300, 50, 200)
    //   .setStrokeStyle(1, 0xff0000);

    this.carsGroup = this.physics.add.group();
    window.carsGroup = this.carsGroup;
    this.createCar(this, 100, 300, 0, 10, "A");
    this.createCar(this, 600, 600, -1, 270, "B");
    this.createCar(this, 400, 300, -0.44, 10, "C");
    this.createCar(this, 600, 700, 0, 170, "D");
    // this.createCar(this, 700, 600, -1.44, 120);
  }

  createCar(scene, x, y, angle, speed, name) {
    const car = new Car(scene, x, y, angle, speed);
    car.name = name; // for debug
    this.carsGroup.children.iterate((c) => {
      c.raycaster.mapGameObjects(car, true);
      car.raycaster.mapGameObjects(c, true);
      c.scene.physics.add.collider(c, car, c.handleCollision);
      car.scene.physics.add.collider(car, c, car.handleCollision);
    });
    this.carsGroup.add(car);
  }

  update() {
    this.carsGroup.children.iterate((car) => {
       // Check if the list item is valid
      if (!car) {
        return;
      }

      if (!this.cameras.main.worldView.contains(car.x, car.y)) {
        // Remove Car from Group and destroy Object
        this.carsGroup.remove(car, true, true);
      } else {
        car.update();
        car.debug();
      }
    });
  }
}

const config = {
  type: Phaser.WEBGL,
  width: 1280,
  height: 1024,
  parent: "phaser-example",
  physics: {
    default: "arcade",
  },
  plugins: {
    scene: [
      {
        key: "PhaserRaycaster",
        plugin: PhaserRaycaster,
        mapping: "raycasterPlugin",
      },
    ],
  },
  scene: Example,
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.60.0/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser-raycaster@0.10.9/dist/phaser-raycaster.js"></script>
```